# Ncat throws errors while being run from crontab

Tags: linux, bash, cron, wget, openwrt

I have a simple script set up on my OpenWrt box to check if one of the computers in a local network is streaming, and if it does, the script starts wget | madplay to play the stream. Script works great if I run it (as a root), but fails if I put in crontab.

Root crontab entry

```
@reboot /root/check.sh > /root/check.log 2>&1
```

Script - check.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
while :; do
    checkProcess=$(/usr/bin/pgrep /usr/bin/madplay)
    if [ "$checkProcess" = "" ]; then
        /usr/bin/ncat -w 0.1 192.168.0.10 50000
        output=$?
        if [ $output == "0" ]; then
            /usr/bin/wget -O - http://192.168.0.10:50000/stream/ | /usr/bin/madplay -
        fi
    fi
    sleep 2
done
```

And the error - from check.log

```
Unable to register IOD #2: Operation not permitted
```

Also, if you have any advice how to improve the script generally, I'll take it gladly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was going to hazard an answer with this, but it's not really a solution, it's more of a clue I found on a Fedora Updates List.


Update Information:

- use select as default nsock engine
- prevents following error:
Unable to register IOD #2: Operation not permitted
**when /dev/null is used as stdin**


https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/test/2013-January/112978.html

Comment: yes, I've found the similar issue on ncat forum, but I'm not sure how to set the default nsock engine. Should I change source and build ncat? Or is there a config that escaped my eye?

and thanks for the clue :)

Comment: Does it work if you run it from root or a user crontab say every 10 mins? Also, if it is this stdin issue, maybe you can create a stdin for ncat with echo | /usr/bin/ncat -w 0.1 192.168.0.10 50000